# Болезненный заусенец или болезненная заусеница?

Tags: лексика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "болезненный заусенец" или "болезненная заусеница"?

Answer (score 1):

Верны оба варианта.

Орфографический словарь
заусенец, -нца, тв. -нцем, р. мн. -нцев и заусеница, -ы, тв. -ей, р. мн. -ниц

заусенец, -нца, тв. -нцем, р. мн. -нцев и заусеница, -ы, тв. -ей, р. мн. -ниц

Большой толковый словарь
ЗАУСЕНЕЦ, -нца; м.
1.
=Заусеница (1 зн.). Ногти в красных заусенцах.
2. Техн.
Острый выступ, неровность на поверхности чего-л. З. на плохо обработанной детали. От кувалды на отливке остался з.

ЗАУСЕНИЦА, -ы; ж.
1.
Задравшаяся кожица у основания ногтя. Болезненная з. З. покраснела. Руки с заусеницами около ногтей. Пальцы в заусеницах.
2. Техн.
=Заусенец (2 зн.). Свинцовая з. З. на детали колет руки. Гладко оструганные бруски без заусениц.

Русское словесное ударение
заусенец, -нца и заусеница,-ы

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&word=%E7%E0%F3%F1%2A

Answer (score 0):

Слово "заусенец" мужского рода. Так что, "болезненный заусенец".